# Flexbox, posso usar sem medo em 2017?

Tags: css3, flexbox

Senhores, encontrei uma página com sistema de grids tipo o bootstrap, mais em flexbox, alguém aqui usa o flexbox atualmente em seus projetos? está dando certo? ou precisa ainda de muitos prefixos?
[Flexbox grid](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

Comment: Assim como a outra, esta pergunta soa bastante opinativa, e esse tipo de pergunta não é permitido no site. Dá uma visitada no http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ´para conhecer melhor o site e ver o que pode e o que não pode ser perguntado.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem nada que você possa usar sem medo, nem em 2017, nem nunca, ainda mais em se tratando de CSS :) Até algo aparentemente inocente como a propriedade `opacity` pode causar efeitos inesperados dependendo de como e onde for usada (pior: nesse caso nem é um problema de compatibilidade entre browsers, é parte da especificação do CSS mesmo).

Sua pergunta está recebendo votos de fechamento porque ninguém vai poder responder "sim" ou "não" pra isso. Quem vai ter de decidir se e quando usar o flexbox é você mesmo, e você só vai poder tomar a decisão com base em dados. A primeira coisa é olhar o link do [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) que o Felipe Torres citou na resposta dele. É a referência mais prática de se consultar sobre compatibilidade de CSS.

Os dados lá mostram que hoje o suporte é bem decente, se você estiver disposto a deixar as coisas quebrarem no IE 11 – que tem uma "grande quantidade de bugs" segundo o caniuse. Mas claro que no mundo real as coisas não são tão verdes quando aparecem nas tabelas do caniuse, como é possível ver nesta [lista de incompatibilidades de flexbox](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs), que parece estar sendo mantida atualizada e cita diversas versões de vários browsers.

Meu conselho é: se você tem "medo" de usar algo, não use. Procure se informar bem sobre como aquilo funciona, e procure dados concretos como os do caniuse (mas não só lá). Quanto mais informação você tiver, menos "medo" vai ter, e será possível tomar uma decisão ponderada, baseada em fatos.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, está dando certo.

Se sua dúvida é em relação à aceitação do Flexbox nas plataformas, uma ferramenta bem legal é o CanIUse.

Você vê exatamente quais plataformas e versões aceitam o que você procura:

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox